# How to go from View to Webform, submit Return to View

Tags: views, 8, webforms

User is working a list of names with Views... select a link on the view to open webform, submit the webform.  Then I would like to return the user to the view.. Where he can continue working the list of names.

Hopefully save url to a hidden token in the view (which token is current url?) then send token in the link to webform pre-populating hidden object in webform?
Back button is a bad idea because I don't want to go back to the webform.  I want to return to the View.

Comment: Might not be what you are after but could you just open the webform link in a new tab...?

Comment: Would be nice, however, I have been told to make it simple for the user, ie: Click to return the list in the view... so they can continue entering results.

Answer (score 1):

Does your views page had a direct url? E.g. www.mysite.com/my-views-url? If so you can just redirect the webform on submit

- Edit the webform, select settings tab
- Select confirmation tab
- Chose either

  - URL (redirects to a custom path or URL)
  - URL with message (redirects to a custom path or URL and displays the confirmation message at the top of the page)
- Set the url in Confirmation URL to redirect back to your view

[image]

Comment: That is my plan, however I so far am unable to get the token view.url.relative into the link to the webform containing the values for populating elements.  Then I hope the confirmation URL will allow me to insert a token.